# Running docker on a non-linux OS

Tags: windows, macos, docker

A docker tutorial says

> Docker is a tool that allows developers, sys-admins etc. to easily
> deploy their applications in a sandbox (called containers) to run on
> the host operating system i.e. Linux.

Can the host operating system be Mac or Windows?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are docker applications [for Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) and [for macOS](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/), but under the hood they run a linux VM (or use WSL).

So you'd essentially be using your host OS to run Linux, which in turn can be used to run containers.

Comment: @zell WSL is short for [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/about)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, no it can't.

What you can do is have a virtual machine with Linux and let that be the docker host.

There are products that simplify this process for [Windows](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/install/) and [MacOSX](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/), specifically for Docker.

*Docker uses many features only available in Linux. There are efforts to implement the required features in other kernels, specifically Windows NT kernel. But at the moment Docker is a Linux only product.*